# Ontologies on the notarial domain

Tags: semantic-web, ontology

I am completely new to ontologies and have been doing some research on representing notarial deeds in the historical domain (ie: old acts) using ontologies and RDF to create a knowledge graph.

I am having a hard time finding an ontology on this particular domain. Did anyone encounter such ontologies? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could ask your question on http://opendata.stackexchange.com. Or create such ontology yourself. Anyway, describe your requirements in more details.

Comment: Usually in such documents one will find parties involved in an event such as a will, donation etc... These will include also dates, items involved and relationships between the parties. I thought about creating the ontology myself but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if something already exists.